# How to combine multiple arrays obtained from mysql queries and then traverse through the new array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I'm trying to build an image uploading website and wish to access a mysql table using a query ..now I wish to store all the arrays obtained from these queries into one single array. I then wish to access all the elements of this array. How should I do it?

This is what I tried:

```
$allimages = array();

$sql="SELECT uploaderId FROM foostable WHERE foo='bar'";//a query which fetches the image uploader's id from the foostable ..you don't need to worry about this part just know that this query returns more than one uploaderIds
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $uploaderId=$row['uploaderId'];

    $sql1="SELECT uploader FROM imagestable WHERE uploaderId='$uploaderId' ORDER BY datetime DESC";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);     

    $allimages=$allimages+$row1;

}

foreach ($allimages as $ai) {
    echo $ai['uploader'];
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'uploader' in...`

I'm definitely doing something wrong but am not able to figure out what that is.

I've been looking everywhere for this but am not able to find it therefore I posted this question! I'm really new to this and any help would be really really appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: What do you have inside `$allimages`? Could you do a `var_dump($allimages)` or `print_r($allimages)` and show the result?

Comment: This is what it shows : `Array ( [uploader] => klara ) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding new elements to your array the wrong way.

Change

```
$allimages=$allimages+$row1;
```

to

```
$allimages[] = $row1; // Short for array_push($allimages, $row1)
```

Read more about [`array_push()` in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a single query to obtain the desired results. Please try the following code:

```
$allimages = array();
$sql    =   "SELECT i.uploader, i.datetime 
                FROM imagestable i INNER JOIN foostable f
                     ON i.uploaderId = f.uploaderId
                    AND f.foo = 'bar'
                ORDER BY i.datetime DESC";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $allimages[] = $row['uploader'];
}

print_r($allimages);
```

Comment: I think it's f.foo

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Was just about making that edit now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.uploader
  FROM foostable f
  JOIN imagestable i
    ON i.uploaderid = f.uploaderId 
 WHERE f.foo = 'bar'
 ORDER 
    BY i.datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
$allImages[] = $row1;
```

This should just push the new array to the end of allImages array everytime the loop runs.